# Removing duplicates from a large dataset

Tags: duplicates

I have a dataset of more than 800000 rows and every even line is a duplicate of the odd one before it. I'd like to remove the duplicates. Please can someone assist?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Could try using this, it uses buffered reading and writing to read/write line by line, skipping every other one. (Currently don't have access to a compiler to get any little bugs out, if you have any problems comment and I'll edit, alright?)

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII"); //Change to the right charset
Path toRead = Paths.get("largefile.txt");
Path toWrite = Paths.get("filteredfile.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(toRead, charset)) {
    String line = null;
    int skip=0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(skip==0)
        {
            skip=1;
            try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(toWrite, charset)) {
                writer.write(line, 0, line.length());
                writer.newLine();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
            }
        }
        else skip=0;
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give more info on that matter, programming language, etc...

My guess is that you should change the query to avoid duplicates (even using a "distinct" should work).

Please post more info so that we can help you.